# Make AutoHotKey ignore Alt as menu key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use autohotkey to simulate elements of Mac keyboard on a PC (Windows) keyboard. My muscle memory reaches for the Command key for simple tasks like copying and pasting, so I'd like to remap the left alt+letter key combinations to appropriate ctrl+letter.

```
<!c::Send ^c
```

Most of the time it works fine, except for part of the time in IE and Office applications. When pressing the left Alt, it screws with the office ribbon/menus (i.e. the menu bar shows in IE, or ribbon letters start appearing in Office 2010), and the ctrl+letter combination fired does not reach destination.

I've read the AHK FAQ + forums, tried a couple of options with UP and $ modifiers to the hotkey, but it did not fix the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

This prevents the left-hand side Alt key from activating the menu bar for most applications (under Windows 7 and AutoHotkey 1.1.11.01):

```
~LAlt Up:: return
```

It doesn't work with Internet Explorer but I don't use IE often anyway. :)

BTW, I also killed the annoying start menu popup via:

```
~LWin Up:: return
~RWin Up:: return
```

Comment: @certainlyakey If this answer solved your issue, consider accepting it

Comment: it wasn't me who wrote the post.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
LAlt::LCtrl
```

put it into a ahk file compile it and run .exe with administrator rights

right click -> Run as administrator

I tested it on Windows 7 and it works, LAlt no longer fires anywhere and it is completely replaced with LCtrl.

Comment: The "Run as administrator" does seem to do the trick with your mapping, but it's too global - I lose important Windows shortcuts such as Alt-Tab. Have you got any idea what might work with the more specific shortcuts such as those I made?

Comment: Prefixing the hotkey with tilde makes it even worse - now alt works normally, i.e. Alt+V opens View menu in IE rather than pasting the clipboard. Maybe I am doing something wrong? The relevant line from script now looks like this:  `~<!v::Send ^v`

Comment: Read this: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm .   You have two choices either make alt work as ctrl or not, the computer doesn't know when to activate alt or ctrl, if you want separate functions for a specific combination you have to code it. Read the docs, try it, write some code, if it doesn't help, post a question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked this on Win-7 and it works, even with IE.

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 1d 00 38 00 38 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Here is the SwapCtrlAlt.reg text.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,1d,00,38,00,38,00,1d,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, they deserve an upvote as quite informative, but I cannot really award the bounty. Like with other suggestions to swap alt with ctrl globally, I lose important Windows shortcuts such as Alt-Tab in this way, that is why I wanted to do this with AHK. Otherwise swapping alt with ctrl (or any other keys) can be done with the GUI utility KeyTweak, which I already know.

Comment: Just for your information, I checked if Send, {vkA4sc038} and Send, {vkA2sc01D} would work, but even if you disable Alt::Return and Ctrl::Return, IE continues to respond because it looks at the low level Scan Codes directly, so only a program (or regedit) that directly controls the scancodes will address this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the wildcard modifier.  This will make it so if your hotkey is pressed in conjunction with another key.  The mapping still works.  Give the following a try:

```
*LAlt::LCtrl
```

This will make <kbd>Alt</kbd> fire <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for any <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Key combination.

Comment: Sorry to report that it didn't help. The IE menu bar, for instance, still flashes up when I press Alt, and it eats the Ctrl+key combination. It seems to me that I need a way for Windows to stop recognizing Alt as soon as it is down, and only recognize the whole key combination only once it has been fully pressed and depressed.

Comment: Ah, I do see this behavior.  Mapping Alt to Return disables it, but once another combination is added, alt activates the menu. I tried a few things but was unable to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
LAlt::LCtrl
```

this will replace `LAlt` with `LCtrl`

Comment: See my comments on answer by Elliot DeNolf - this does not solve the problem I experience.

Answer (score 0):

you could also swap the two buttons.

Something like:

```
LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LAlt
```

In the limited testing I did, it works, but you might need to relearn some of your window key shortcuts.  It basically just swaps the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that IE behaves differently from most other applications.
You could try the instructions below. This is NOT autoHotKey but regedit changes.
B.t.w. I had checked to see if ScanCodes would work (SC38 for LAlt), but IE still ignores that.

Not sure if this works in Vista/Win7/8, but worth a look.

http://www.designcodeexecute.com/2006/11/04/swap-alt-and-ctrl-keys-in-windows-xp/